# Create DataFrame with a loop-based numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, append

I am doing an for loop in order to compute statistical values. For this, I'm storing the computations from a column in different variables (D10, D50 and D90).

Then I store them in an array called result

```python
# First created an empty numpy array

result_array = np.array([])

for column in df:
    
    # just computations you can ignore them

    df = df.sort_values('Size')
    
    cumul = df[column].cumsum()
    
    suma_de_frecuencias = df[column].sum()
    
    D10 = sum(cumul < 0.1 * float(suma_de_frecuencias))
    
    D50 = sum(cumul < 0.5 * float(suma_de_frecuencias))
    
    D90 = sum(cumul < 0.9 * float(suma_de_frecuencias))
    
    # List of statistics values i am trying to get
    
    D10 = df['Size'].iloc[D10]
    
    D50 = df['Size'].iloc[D50]
    
    D90 = df['Size'].iloc[D90]

    
    # Storing values in an array

    result = [D10, D50, D90]
    
    # Appending each "result" in "result_array"

    result_array = np.append(result_array, result)
```

But when I try to create a dataframe, the code result to be an error

```python
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data=result_array[1:,1:],index=result_array[1:,65],column=result_array[0,1:])
```

It results in an IndexError Traceback in line 40 which is for dataset

Saying:

IndexError: too many indices for array

[IndexError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoIIX.png)

What i would like to get is something like this:

```python
"""    
        'D10'  |  'D50'  |  'D90'
   0 |  value  |  value  |  value    <--- the first computated array "result"
   1 |  value  |  value  |  value    <--- the first computated array "result"
   2 |  value  |  value  |  value    <--- the first computated array "result"
   3 |  value  |  value  |  value  
   .
   .
   .

"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with you indexing a 1-D array.

result_array is simple an (n * 1) array which cannot be indexed into further columns.

Try to append a multi-dimensional array as below -

```
result_array = result_array.reshape(len(result_array)//3,3)
```

**Creating a dataframe**

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame(data = result_array, columns = ['D10', 'D50', 'D90'])
```

Output -

Please note that I have created the dataframe with sample values.

[image]